# how to traverse soap response with curl request in php?

Tags: php, xml, web-services, curl, soap

How to get the value inside the tag  of the soap response in php.The response is like this.

```
string '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<GetListResponse xmlns="http://test.org/">
<GetListResult>[{"Id":30,"Name":"OFFICE"},{"Id":31,"Name":"KUMAR KHATRI"},{"Id":32,"Name":"ASHA MAIYA SHRESTHA"},{"Id":33,"Name":"RABINDRA GHIMIRE"},{"Id":34,"Name":"CHABBI GHIMIRE"},{"Id":35,"Name":"RAJ KUMAR SHRESTHA"},{"Id":36,"Name":"RABINDRA BDH. RO'... (length=614)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of `GetListResult` you may do like this:

```
$source = <<<EOS
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<GetListResponse xmlns="http://test.org/">
<GetListResult>
[{"Id":30,"Name":"OFFICE"},{"Id":31,"Name":"KUMAR KHATRI"},{"Id":32,"Name":"ASHA MAIYA SHRESTHA"},{"Id":33,"Name":"RABINDRA GHIMIRE"},{"Id":34,"Name":"CHABBI GHIMIRE"},{"Id":35,"Name":"RAJ KUMAR SHRESTHA"}]
</GetListResult>
</GetListResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
EOS;

// Create simple XML element
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($source);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('test', 'http://test.org/');

// Get value of first "GetListResponse" element
$result = (string)$xml->xpath('//test:GetListResult')[0];

// Parse JSON
$values = json_decode($result, true);
var_dump($values);
```

Output:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Id"]=>
    int(30)
    ["Name"]=>
    string(6) "OFFICE"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Id"]=>
    int(31)
    ["Name"]=>
    string(12) "KUMAR KHATRI"
  }
...
}
```

There is also some [SOAP functionality integrated in PHP itself](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php). If you could make use of that, you would be able to remove the use of CURL + SimpleXMLElement altogether. Something like this (untested):

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("http://test.org/wsdl?WSDL");
$soapResult = $soapClient->SomeFunction(array('foo'=>'bar', 'baz'=>'fez'));
$result = $soapResult->GetListResponse->GetListResult;
```